# Buttons not rendering on website - should have a white background

Tags: html, css

The site is [http://freetorun.net/choose/](http://freetorun.net/choose)
The buttons should have a white background.  I have looked and cannot figure out the issue.  Sorry but not sure if you need the entire page of HTML or just the section with the issue.
Any light you can shine on this is appreciated!
Spencer

```
    div style="text-align: center;"><a class="small-light-button" title="Buy Now" href="http://freetorun.net/running-level-1-registration/">Buy Now</a></div>
</div></div>
</div>
<div class="one_fourth">
<div class="custom" style="background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #0352bd, #011633) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
                           background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#0352bd), to(#011633));
                                               background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0352bd 0%,#011633 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                                               background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0352bd 0%,#011633 99%); /* IE10+ */
                           margin-left:0 !important;
                           margin-right:0 !important;
                           border:1px solid #3D5C00;
                           background-color: #011633;
                           width:100%;
                           color:#FFFFFF;"><div class="inner-padding">
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><span style="font-size: 30px; color: #ffffff;">POSE Running Clinic</span></h4>
<h3 style="color: #ffffff;">Level 2</h3>
<h5 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><span style="font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;">$125.00</span></h5>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is the button  you are talking about, `<a class="small-light-button" title="Buy Now" href="http://freetorun.net/running-level-1-registration/">Buy Now</a>`, we would need to see what css is defined for **small-light-button**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your button really should look like, but you don't need a background image here.

Add something like

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(237,237,237,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
border: 2px solid white;
padding: 0px 8px !important;
```

to your button style.

And

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
```

to the hover style.
This is similar to the background-image you had in your styles.

Answer (score 0):

There is that background in

```
a.small-light-button{
    background: transparent url(../../common-images/small-light-button-l.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
}
```

Which screws up everything, delete it. Then you must add :

```
background-color: #fff;
```

that's a start. You should really think of factorising your design code using stylesheets *.css, look that up on google.

That should organise your design, and makes it easy to maintain and improve in the future !